# Right circular shift in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `mxn` composed of zeros and ones, and a matrix `J` of dimension `mx1` reporting some integers from `{1,...,n}`.

I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `mxn` such that for

(1) `B(1,:)=A(1,:)`

(2) for `i=2,...,m`, `B(i,:)` is obtained by shifting `A(i,:)` right circular of a number of positions equal to `(J(1)-1)+ (J(2)-1)+...+ (J(i-1)-1)`

**Clarification**: by *shifting a vector `C` right circular of a number of positions `q`* I mean the following (more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift#Example))

```
%Example 1
C=[a b c d e];
q=4; %q<size(C,2)
%a should go to position 1+q=5
%b should go to position 2+q=6 ---> 1 
%c should go to position 3+q=7 ---> 2
%d should go to position 4+q=8 ---> 3 
%e should go to position 5+q=9 ---> 4 
C_new=[b c d e a];

%Example 2
C=[a b c d e];
q=2; %q<size(C,2)
%a should go to position 1+q=3
%b should go to position 2+q=4  
%c should go to position 3+q=5
%d should go to position 4+q=6 ---> 1 
%e should go to position 5+q=7 ---> 2 
C_new=[d e a b c];
```

This code does what I want

```
m=4;
n=5;
A=[1 1 1 1 1; ...
   0 0 1 0 0; ...
   1 0 1 0 1; ...
   0 1 0 0 1];
J=[1;2;1;4];
B=zeros(m,n);
B(1,:)=A(1,:);
foridx=cumsum(J);
for i=2:m
    shift=foridx(i-1)-(i-1);
    newidx=(1:1:n)+shift; 
    for j=1:n
        if newidx(j)>n
           newidx(j)=newidx(j)-n;
        end
    end
    for j=1:n
        B(i,newidx(j))=A(i,j);
    end

end
```

However, it is very slow for `m,n` large. Could you suggest some way to vectorise the algorithm?

---

Thanks to a suggestion below I was able to modify the code as

```
 B=zeros(m,n);
 B(1,:)=A(1,:);
 foridx=cumsum(J);
 for i=2:m
     shift=foridx(i-1)-(i-1);
     B(i,:)=circshift(A(i,:).',shift,1);
 end
```

Still, I would like to delete also the loop over `i`. Any suggestion?

Comment: have you read about this function: [circshift](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html)

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks for your comment. Why do you say that `(J(1)-1)+ (J(2)-1)+...+ (J(i-1)-1)` should give `4`? for `i=2` it gives `0`; for `i=3` it gives `1`; for `i=4` it gives `1`. Am I doing some mistakes?

Comment: @SardarUsama There is an index `i-1`. For each `i=2,...,m` you want to sum up to `i-1`. That's why the last element of `J` is never considered.

Comment: @ammportal Thanks a lot, I didn't know about this function. Still, I would love to delete also the external loop over `i`

Comment: @SardarUsama When i=4, then the shift is `J(1)-1+ J(2)-1 +J(3)-1=0+1+0=1`

Comment: Refer to the duplicate, Divakar's and Tasos' answers in particular if you're not familiar with the Octave syntax

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks a lot, that solved my problem